# What's the different between JPDA and JMX?

Tags: jmx, jpda

I am trying to write a application monitoring tools, and I came across two standards, JPDA and JMX. They seems like some how similar to me. What's the different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JPDA](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/) is used for *debugging* and [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) for monitoring. If you are developing a monitoring tool - the choice is obvious, unless your monitor is suppose to handle breakpoints, be notified on exceptions, etc.